# Convergence of a sequence and root test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am working on some sequence problems and had trouble with a particular one. I believe the sequence is divergent but I couldn't really prove it: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt[4]{n^3+2n}}.$$ I tried assuming that the sequence converges to a limit $L$ and then doing some algebraic manipulation to show that it leads to a contradiction but after a while I couldn't show that it diverges for certain: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^{1/4})(\sqrt{n+ \frac{1}{n}}-1)}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}
$$
One thought that occurred to me was using the root test for series but I don't know if they're applicable to series of if my professor would accept it so I would appreciate any help on this honestly.

Comment: You ask about a limit of something as n goes to infinity. That is the limit of a *sequence*. It is not a series(=sum) so the root test isn't relevant.

Comment: Can you see that the expression is asymptotically $\frac{n}{n^{3/4}} = n^{1/4}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by the conjugate of the numerator

$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{ \sqrt{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt{n} }{\sqrt[4]{n^3 + 2n}} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{ n^2 - n + 1 }{\left(\sqrt[4]{n^3 + 2 n}\right) \left( n \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} } + \sqrt{n} \right) } \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^2 - n + 1}{ \left(n^{\frac{3}{4}} \sqrt[4]{1 + 2 n^{-2} }\right) \left(n \left( \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \right) } \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^2 - n + 1} { n^{\frac{7}{4}} \left( \sqrt[4]{1 + 2 n^{-2}} \right) \left( \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2}} \right) } \end{split}\end{equation} $

And this limit does not exist, as the fraction approaches $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sequence, therefore you cannot apply series criterion.

We want to compute
$$ 
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt[4]{n^{3}+2 n}}
$$

We have can use equivalents : $\sqrt[4]{n^{3}+2 n} \sim n^\frac{3}{4}$ and $ \sqrt{n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{n} \sim n$ therefore $\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt[4]{n^{3}+2 n}} \sim \frac{n}{n^\frac{3}{4}} = n^\frac{1}{4}$ which diverges.